# reverse of a Gaussian diffusion process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Imagine I have a diffusion process described by the equation $x_1 = f(x_0) + a \cdot \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a random Gaussian number. The way this process evolves from $x_0$ to $x_1$ follows a certain conditional probability called $q(x_1 | x_0)$.

Now, the question is whether I can find a kind of "reverse" diffusion process that goes from $x_1$ back to $x_0$. This reverse process might be represented as $x_0 = g(x_1) + b \cdot \eta$, with $\eta$ being another Gaussian random number. The interesting part is that I want the conditional probability for this reverse process, denoted as $p(x_0 | x_1)$, to be exactly the same as the $q(x_1 | x_0)$ from the original process.

Comment: Can you write the generic step $x_{k+1}=...?$ You will need the Gaussian noise steps to be independent i.e. $x_{k+1}=f(x_{k})+\epsilon_{k}$. Then if the f is nice, you might get a Markov chain and thus you can  try showing reversibility: http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-Time-Reversibility.pdf

Comment: I am just considering a single step of diffusion. The note you showed does not shown that the conditional probability of the forward and reverse diffusion are the same. @ThomasKojar

Comment: $x_0=f^{-1}(x_1-a\epsilon)$

Comment: This is not a diffusion process. @user619894

Comment: Right, I don't think there is one, the noise goes through a nonlinear transformation and is not Gaussian any more.